# Can't display datetime from v-for

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to show the datatime in a v-for, but it just keeps showing the same time over and over.

Is there a way to do this?

v-for -

```
<div class="location-box-container">
  <ul class="location-box-list">
    <ol v-for="(location, index) in lineStringData" :key="lineStringData.id">
      <p class="locations">{{ location_time }}  New Location</p>
    </ol>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS -

```
  data() {
    return {
      location_time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
    }
  },
```

Comment: What's `lineStringData`?

Comment: Because `location_time` isn't in array?

Comment: @raina77ow An array of coordinates

Comment: @gre_gor Correct, the array is lineStringData. So I assume it should be location instead of location_time then. How do i get the time stamp for that?

Comment: So timestamp is stored on each element of that array? If so, how does each element look like?

Comment: @raina77ow No, I'm simply printing out when a new set of coordinates is updated.  just need to show a local datetime when the new set is updated.

Comment: @raina77ow I need more the datetime of an individual event

Comment: Ah, I see. So you need to show updated time only for the locations that actually were updated? You might consider using two approaches here: either adjust the data when it arrives to your component (and add time there as element's property) or use method within your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a method to lookup time.  Not sure where you are storing the time, but you can look up timezone from coords if needed.

```
<div class="location-box-container">
  <ul class="location-box-list">
    <ol v-for="(location, index) in lineStringData" :key="lineStringData.id">
      <p class="locations">{{ getTime(location) }}  New Location</p>
    </ol>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
methods: {
    getTime(location) {
      // lookup your timezone, etc here.
      return new Date(location.theTime).toLocaleTimeString()
    }
}
```